# `plugins_api()`: why does a commercial plugin changelog link result in a tailing plugins repo check and 500 error?

Tags: plugins, updates

On some sites, I'm not able to load commercial plugin changelogs from update screen modal.

`https://<site>/wp-admin/plugin-install.php?tab=plugin-information&plugin=ithemes-security-pro&section=changelog` results in "An unexpected error occurred. Something may be wrong with WordPress.org or this server’s configuration. If you continue to have problems, please try the support forums."

Tracing the request reveals that IThemes API call succeeds fine and gets the changelog.

But then the core plugin repo check follows, and since `ithemes-security-pro` doesn't exist there, the whole process fails.

I've seen the same thing happen for other commercial plugins, so it seems like a more general problem.

Anybody here perhaps know what mechanism is to blame?

**Zoom in towards callgraph bottom**
[image: Zoom in towards callgraph bottom]

**Full request callgraph**
[image: Full request callgraph]